# Laravel Navbar search multiple models

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I'm using [this](https://packagist.org/packages/nicolaslopezj/searchable) package for search in my laravel project which works fine.

What im looking for is to create a search like on [this website](https://www.practo.com/)

I have a navbar partial that includes a search form which is displayed on every page. I have a search page, blog search page, news search page and so on. And im planning to use twitter typeahead to display suggestions while user enters a query. I want to display suggestions from multiple models which redirects the user to the particular search page. For example, when i type hello, it searches from all the models and dislpays items with hello in news, blog etc. And when i click on hello in news suggestion, it should take me to news/search page with the results, similary for blog which should take me to blog/search page with the request.

I have never implemented a search like this. I do not want to use a search engine like elastic or algolia as such large system is not required for my project.

Comment: Have you looked into using Laravel Scout?  It looks like it uses Algolia but if you really don't want to use that, it appears there are MySQL drivers for it as well.

Comment: I have elasticsearch 6.0 installed on my machine which works fine on :9200 but i could not find laravel scout drivers for elasticsearch 6.0. I could only find for 5.0 version. And i do not want to use Algolia,

Comment: sadly the only driver that support multi index search is algolia, any other driver requires hacks